# Generic dispatcher class

Tags: c++, templates, events, generics

I'm trying to write a class that does event (or whatever) dispatching in a generic way. The template parameters are the event listener's type, the event type to be passed as argument, and the function to be called on the listener (member function). This is the class definition:

```
template<class L, class E, void (L::*F)(const E&)>
class Dispatcher {

  public:

     typedef L ListenerType;
     typedef E EventType;

     Dispatcher ();
     virtual ~Dispatcher ();

     void addListener(ListenerType* listener);
     void removeListener(ListenerType* listener);
     void dispatch (const EventType& event);

  protected:

     std::vector<ListenerType*> mListeners;

};
```

The definition of the dispatch method:

```
template<class L, class E, void (L::*F)(const E&)>
void Dispatcher<L, E, F>::dispatch (const EventType& event) {
     for (int i = 0; i < mListeners.size(); ++i) {
        if(mListeners[i]) {
           (mListeners[i]->*F)(event);
        }
     }
}
```

And finally the test case:

```
struct E {
   unsigned int count;
};

class A {
   public:
      void fun(const E& e) {
         std::cout << "Count = " << e.count;
      }
};

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

   Dispatcher<A, E, &A::fun> disp;
   A a;
   E e;
   e.count = 10;
   disp.addListener(&a);
   disp.dispatch(e);
   return 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is that it runs as expected, outputs "Count = 10", but the compiler states:

```
..\bcore/Dispatcher.h: In instantiation of 'void ts::Dispatcher<L, E, F>::dispatch(const EventType&) [with L = A; E = E; void (L::* F)(const E&) = &A::fun; ts::Dispatcher<L, E, F>::EventType = E]':
..\main.cpp:575:19:   required from here
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What *we* are missing is what *else* the compiler is saying - what you posted is only part of a full message.

Comment: Works for me (after adding my own add/remove listener function as you didn't provide them) and I'm not getting that message.

Comment: Is it a warning about comparing signed and unsigned types (`i` and `mListeners.size()`)? Declare `i` as `size_t` - or `std::vector<ListenerType*>::size_type` for the language lawyers. (and yes, the difference between typing `int` and `std::vector<ListenerType*>::size_type` is plenty of motivation to switch to C++11 for `auto`.)

Comment: As an aside, `std::function` is really made for this.  Gets rid of dependency on listener type.  You do need a token to disconnect: I like storing `std::weak_ptr<std::function>` in dispatcher and using `std::shared_ptr<std::function>` as my token, which does not even have to be returned...  So my `Dispatcher<Args...>` has a variadic signature, and `dispatch(Args... args)` consumes the same set, and I store `std::weak_ptr<std::function<void(Args...)>>` which I lock, check, and call.  The listening object keeps the RAII token around so long as it wants to listen, and bob is your mothers brother.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I knew that the comparison is between signed and unsigned types, but I encountered the warning so many times before, I thought it is a separate warning message. I'll have a look at std::function. Thank you all for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it compiles and runs, then it is likely warning about the comparison between the signed integer (`i`) and unsigned integer (`vector::size()`) in `Dispatcher::dispatch`.  The return-type from `vector::size()` is `vector::size_type`, an unsigned integral type.

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < mListeners.size(); ++i) { ... }
            //  '-^------------------' signed < unsigned comparison
```

To remove the compiler warning, declare `i` as an `unsigned int`:

```cpp
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mListeners.size(); ++i) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. I thought the signedness warning to be a separate message.